# MySQL database - query to only update certain fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

I would like to run and mysqli UPDATE on my registerUsers table, so once I hit the update button, it updates the fields that have been updated.

I need it to update the first name, surname, and email and do nothing if the password fields are blank.
If the password is filled in, I want it to update all fields.

The commented out code (is passwords fields are ''/empty, doesn't seem to work..

Any ideas how I would do this?

```
<?php

 include 'dbconnect.php';
 include 'dumpr.php';

session_start();

if( ! $_SESSION['username'] ) {

header("Location: project-users-logout.php");
die();
}

$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registeredUsers WHERE UserID=$userid";

$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


//Clean form values
$cleanFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmName']);
$cleanSurname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmSurname']);
$cleanEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmEmail']);

//Clean password
$password   = sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmPassword1']));

if (isset($_POST['Update']) && $_POST['Update'] == "Update") {


if ( ( $_POST['frmName'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmSurname'] != '') &&
     ($_POST['frmEmail'] != '') 
 //       && ($_POST['frmPassword1'] = '') && ($_POST['frmPassword2'] = '') 
   )

{

    $sql2 = "UPDATE registeredUsers SET FirstName = '$cleanFirstName', Surname = '$cleanSurname', EmailAddress='$cleanEmail' WHERE UserID='$userid'";

        $upQry = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);

        if ($upQry) { 
             /* SUCCESS */ 
             header ("Location: project-users-manage.php ");
             exit;
        } else {
             /* FAIL */ 
   }

  }
} 


?>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Password 1</th>
<th>Password 2</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<?php 

echo "<form action='' method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input disabled='disabled' type=text name=user value=" .    $row['UserName'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='frmName' value=" . $row['FirstName'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='frmSurname' value=" . $row['Surname'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='frmEmail' value=" . $row['EmailAddress'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='frmPassword1' value=''  " . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name='frmPassword2' value=''  " . "</td>";    
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='Update' value='Update'></td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</tr>";


header("Location: project-users-manage.php"); 
exit;
```

?>

Comment: `=` != `===`! You're assigning '' to $_POST['password'], not comparing it! so change '=' to '===' there!

Comment: You're not actually checking that the password's match, ie. all that is required to execute the `UPDATE` query is to put a random string in the password field. You need to verify the user's password.

Comment: And don't do this: `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['frmPassword1'])` Leave the user's password alone. Simply hash it. Don't escape quotes (by adding a \ to their password), don't trim whitespace, don't convert to special chars/html entities, etc, etc, etc. Just hash it. Preferably with [password_hash()](http://php.net/password)

Comment: Write **method='post'** instead of method=post.

Comment: You're not closing a single one of your `input`'s

Comment: Marcus... where do i close them... i.e. place the '>'? it's causing me issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `''` to `$_POST['frmPassword1]` here:

```
&& ($_POST['frmPassword1'] = '') && ($_POST['frmPassword2'] = '')
```

but you actually want to compare it:

```
&& ($_POST['frmPassword1'] === '') && ($_POST['frmPassword2'] === '')
```

I would implement the wanted logic like that:

```
if ( ( $_POST['frmName'] != '') &&
    ($_POST['frmSurname'] != '') &&
    ($_POST['frmEmail'] != '') 
   )

{
    $updatePwd='';
    if ($_POST['frmPassword1'] != '') && ($_POST['frmPassword2'] != '') {
         $updatePwd = ", password='".$_POST['frmPassword1']."' ";
    } 
    $sql2 = "UPDATE registeredUsers SET FirstName = '$cleanFirstName', Surname = '$cleanSurname', EmailAddress='$cleanEmail'";
    $sql2.= $updatePwd." WHERE UserID='$userid'";
    // rest of code....
}
```

**NOTE**
Three important things missing/ommitted in this simple example:
-Escaping user-input
-Use prepared statements
-encrypt password

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
if (( $_POST['frmPassword1'] != '') && ($_POST['frmPassword2'] != '')){
//Query For update All Field
}else{
$sql2 = "UPDATE registeredUsers SET FirstName = '$cleanFirstName', Surname = '$cleanSurname', EmailAddress='$cleanEmail' WHERE UserID='$userid'";
}
```

to update, check the passqord fileds